# How to update a row in an Azure storage table using an Azure Function out binding

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, updating

I'm using an Azure Function to process data stored in an Azure Storage table. The Azure Function is written in PowerShell and is triggered by a timer to run each minute. On each run it will take the first 10 unprocessed rows, process each of those rows and then mark the row as processed by setting a field 'processed' to true. However, it seems that by using the output binding I'm not able to update a row.

I tried updating the rows by using the following configuration and code.

Function bindings:

```
    {
      "tableName": "tobeprocessed",
      "connection": "ProcessStorage",
      "name": "InProcessStorageTableBinding",
      "type": "table",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "tableName": "tobeprocessed",
      "connection": "ProcessStorage",
      "name": "OutProcessStorageTableBinding",
      "type": "table",
      "direction": "out"
    }
```

Function code:

```
param($Timer, $InProcessStorageTableBinding)

# Get first ten unprocessed rows
$InProcessStorageTableBinding | Where-Object { $_.Processed -eq $false } | Select-Object -First 10 | ForEach-Object {

    # Logic for processing the values in the row
    # left out for the sake of brevity

    # Update the row
    $_.Processed = $true
    Push-OutputBinding -Name OutProcessStorageTableBinding -Value $_
}
```

The message that appears in the logs of the Azure Function on the Azure Portal is:

> The specified entity already exists. RequestId:da4224dd-0002-0071-0671-70a732000000 Time:2023-04-16T14:38:05.4671520Z

While searching the internet for possible solutions I found that people are using `Get-AzStorageTable` and `Update-AzTableRow` from the PowerShell module `AzTable` to update rows in Azure Storage tables. But by doing so a lot more configuration is required (certificates, tenant- and app id's, etc) as it seems that by using `Update-AzTableRow` we cannot use the out binding. And the bindings is such a nice feature of Azure Functions since it takes care of all the authentication and connection setup behind the scenes, so I would really prefer to use the out binding if possible.

Update: As Peter Bons pointed out in the answers below, the docs about [Azure Tables output bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-output?tabs=in-process%2Cstorage-extension&pivots=programming-language-powershell) are very clear that updating isn't possible using the bindings.

Would it then maybe be possible to re-use (parts) of the connection that is set up by the bindings to reduce the plumbing needed in order to be able to use (for instance) the PowerShell module `AzTable` to update a row?

So that we could do something like this:

```
$table = Get-AzStorageTable –Connection $InProcessStorageTableBinding.Connection

$cloudTable = $table.CloudTable

$rowToProcess = Get-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -customFilter <filter to retrieve row>

$rowToProcess.Processed = $true

$rowToProcess | Update-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck I am afraid. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-output?tabs=in-process%2Cstorage-extension&pivots=programming-language-python) confirm your suspicion:

> This output binding only supports creating new entities in a table. If you need to update an existing entity from your function code, instead use an Azure Tables SDK directly.

Comment: As @PeterBons mentioned there's a limitation on the output binding. AZBobbyTables is a good option within Azure Functions. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzBobbyTables/3.1.0

Comment: Thanks @BrettMiller, AzBobbyTables looks promising. I will give it a try and report back here 

Comment: AzBobbyTables rocks! It is just what I needed. Thanks again @BrettMiller